# What can be done in the initialization/finalization section and what must be avoided

Tags: delphi

I don't remember why, but I keep the rules to do a minimum think as possible in the `initialization/finalization` sections of my units. I think it's was mostly related to when the project is a **DLL** but don't remember the exact reasons. So this why I want to ask what can be done in a `initialization/finalization` section? for example is it safe to do something like this :

```
initialization
  MyObj := TObjectDictionary<String, TobjectList<TSomething>>.create([doOwnsValues]);

finalization
  FreeAndNil(MyObj);
```

or only very trivial think (ie like A := 10) must be done in `initialization/finalization` section?

Comment: Your example code is perfectly fine.

Comment: It's only for DLLs, and for them the init/finit functions are called from DllMain. So you need to read the remarks from the docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlls/dllmain and also this series from Raymond: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040127-00/?p=40873

Comment: @DavidHeffernan this deserve to be the response :) thanks ! so as I understand doing TObjectDictionary<String, TobjectList<TSomething>>.create([doOwnsValues]); is OK as far as I understand :)

Comment: Yes that is perfectly fine.

Comment: One risk (that I've seen materialize myself) is if the code in initialization/finalization depends on objects created/freed in other units' corresponding sections. In that case, the exact order of unit initialization/finalization becomes important. One usually doesn't want to keep track of that. So avoid that complexity, if possible (it usually is). Your example is perfectly fine; in fact I'd say it's an example of the most typical case.